# Animating stl CAD model and export the animation in fbx format

Tags: animation, export, .fbx, stl

I'm dealing with 3D CAD simulation. I need to animate 3D CAD models (in obj/stl tessellation formats or step exact geometry format) knowing exactly the motion they have to do (matrix/quaternion). After I need to export this simulation in a readable format (I suppose fbx is the most popular). I don't know if blender is the right tool for this.